# What is the best way to display webpage content for a given URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a small labeling tool that given a URL should display a document hosted on that URL and allow a user to choose a label for that document.

I want to display the contents of the URL for this purpose. As far as I know, I can either get the URL content, parse the contents, and display or use an iframe option.

- Without using parser

Iframes are not enabled for the target URL, the contents of which I want to display. Is there any other way to do this using javascript without using parser?

- Using parser

I can crawl the contents of the URL, get everything between   and dump it in the webpage area.

I'm new to javascript and front end development so I am not sure whether these are the only options.

Are there other options to do this?

If the parser is the only option, Can I dump the HTML that I get from the remote URL? I understand that images and other media that may be within  on remote url won't be displayed. Is there any other caveat to this method? More importantly, Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: If a site has Iframes disabled, then I doubt they would have CORS enabled, so loading the page using Ajax would not work either. You can, however, bypass both those security measures using a proxy, and sometimes a browser extension can be set to ignore those settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most sites do it via the iframe like you mentioned like codepen.

Also, you can use [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) ( a headless browser ) to do these sort of things. Get the contents using web scraping or take a screenshot or print a pdf. Pretty nifty library.

> Most things that you can do manually in the browser can be done using
>   Puppeteer! Here are a few examples to get you started:
>
> - Generate screenshots and PDFs of pages. Crawl a SPA (Single-Page    Application) and generate pre-rendered content (i.e. "SSR"
>     (Server-Side Rendering)).
> - Automate form submission, UI testing,    keyboard input, etc. Create an up-to-date, automated testing    environment.
> - Run your tests directly in the latest version of Chrome using the latest JavaScript and browser features.

Hope this helps !